# Limit text length of auto-scrolling NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, nstextview

I have a NSTextView that is displaying what I would call a "rolling log".  New `AttributedString`'s are being added just about every second.  What I would like to do is truncate from the beginning of the `NSTextView` if the string has hit a certain length, or a certain number of lines.  This is so that the displayed log doesn't take up a ton of memory.

How should I best go about this?  I have some code though it doesn't appear to be working as I would expect, specifically around the auto scrolling.

Expected behavior:

- Remove leading lines if needed (I don't really care if this is lines or number of characters, whichever is easiest).
- Auto-scroll to the bottom if the view isn't scrolled up (so if the user has currently scrolled up, they're not auto-scrolled to the bottom).

The code:

```
- (void)append:(TextTag*)text toTextView:(MyNSTextView *) textView {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSAttributedString *attr = [self stringFromTag:text];

        NSScroller *scroller = [[textView enclosingScrollView] verticalScroller];

        double autoScrollToleranceLineCount = 3.0;

        NSUInteger lines = [self countLines:[textView string]];
        double scrolled = [scroller doubleValue];
        double scrollDiff = 1.0 - scrolled;
        double percentScrolled = autoScrollToleranceLineCount / lines;

        BOOL shouldScrollToBottom = scrollDiff <= percentScrolled;

       [textView.textStorage beginEditing];

       if (lines >= 10000) {
           NSRange removeRange = [self getRemovalRange:textView.string];
           [textView.textStorage deleteCharactersInRange:removeRange];
       }

       [[textView textStorage] appendAttributedString:attr];

       [textView.textStorage endEditing];

       if(shouldScrollToBottom) {
           [textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([[textView string] length], 0)];
       }
    });
}

- (NSRange)getRemovalRange:(NSString *)s {

    NSUInteger numberOfLines, index, stringLength = [s length];

    for (index = 0, numberOfLines = 0; index < stringLength;
         numberOfLines++) {
        index = NSMaxRange([s lineRangeForRange:NSMakeRange(index, 0)]);
        if (numberOfLines >= 100) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return NSMakeRange(0, index);
}

- (NSUInteger) countLines:(NSString *)s {

    NSUInteger numberOfLines, index, stringLength = [s length];

    for (index = 0, numberOfLines = 0; index < stringLength;
         numberOfLines++) {
        index = NSMaxRange([s lineRangeForRange:NSMakeRange(index, 0)]);
    }
    return numberOfLines;
}
```

Comment: I've done something similar and the scrolling is performed on the next iteration of the runloop like `[self performSelector:@selector(scrollProgressTextViewToEnd) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];`.

Comment: @Willeke at first go, that appears to be working!  Going to mess with that for a day, but mind adding that as an answer and I can give you credit?

Comment: So after trying that for a few hours, it does still seem to not scroll sometimes.  =/

Comment: Testing it without the use of begin/end editing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did (years ago, trial and error).

```
- (void)scrollProgressTextViewToEnd
{
    if ([progressTextView isFlipped])
        [progressTextView scrollPoint:NSMakePoint(0.0, NSMaxY([progressTextView frame]) - NSHeight([progressTextView visibleRect]))];
    else
        [progressTextView scrollPoint:NSMakePoint(0.0, 0.0)];
}

- (void)appendToProgressText:(NSString *)theString bold:(BOOL)theBold
{
    [progressTextView.textStorage beginEditing];
    [self appendToProgressText:theString bold:theBold];
    [progressTextView.textStorage endEditing];
    [progressTextView didChangeText];
    [self performSelector:@selector(scrollProgressTextViewToEnd) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}
```

Method `appendToProgressText` adds `theString` to `progressTextView.textStorage` and doesn't use `progressTextView`.